# Using QNetworkAccessManager::post to transfer file got QIODevice: device not open

Tags: qt, ubuntu, networking

I am using Qt 5.7.0 on Ubuntu 16.04.1 x64.

When I try to using QNetworkAccessManager::post() to transfer file, it will got Error "QIODevice:device not open".

It's strange that release version of the program will go wrong certainly, while the same problem only occur after a long time running(look like that) in debug version.

Here is relative function:

```
QHttpMultiPart* PacketFactory::getPacket(QString id, QString imgPath) {
    QHttpMultiPart *pMultiPart = new QHttpMultiPart(QHttpMultiPart::FormDataType);

    QHttpPart idPart;
    idPart.setHeader(QNetworkRequest::ContentTypeHeader, QVariant("text/plain"));
    idPart.setHeader(QNetworkRequest::ContentDispositionHeader, QVariant("form-data; name=\"id\""));
    idPart.setBody(id.toUtf8());

    // some text/plain part
    ...

    QFile *imgFile = new QFile(imgPath);
    imgFile->setParent(pMultiPart);
    Q_ASSERT(imgFile->open(QIODevice::ReadWrite));

    QHttpPart imagePart;
    imagePart.setHeader(QNetworkRequest::ContentTypeHeader, QVariant("image/jpeg"));
    imagePart.setHeader(QNetworkRequest::ContentDispositionHeader, QVariant("form-data; name=\"img\"; filename=\"1.jpg\""));
    imagePart.setBodyDevice(imgFile);
    pMultiPart->append(imagePart);

    return pMultiPart;
}
```

Another:

```
QNetworkRequest NetManager::getRequest(int dst) {
    QString url;
    switch (op) {
    case DST_LOCAL:
        url = "http://127.0.0.1/query"
        break;
    ...
    }

    return QNetworkRequest(QUrl(url));
}
```

Here is invoke code:

```
QNetworkRequest request = m_pNetManager->getRequest(NetManager::DST_LOCAL);
QHttpMultiPart *pMultiPart = PacketFactory::getPacket(...);
QNetworkReply *pReply = m_NetworkAccessManager.post(request, pMultiPart);
QObject::connect(pReply, SIGNAL(finished()), this, SLOT(handlePacket()));
pMultiPart->setParent(pReply);
```

Thanks for advices.

Comment: How did you set up your `request` object?

Comment: @RobbieE I updated my code